# Google oAuth2 signin with cross origin isolation

Tags: google-signin, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-opener-policy

I have a web app that relies on SharedArrayBuffer. I turned on cross-origin isolation on my website because google chrome will require it by the end of the month.

However, doing so breaks Google oAuth2 login.

I tried to import the auth script with the cross-origin flag on but not success as it in turns try to import other scripts that are blocked.

login.html

```
...

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init";
script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
script.setAttribute('defer', 'true');
script.setAttribute('crossorigin', '');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
...
```

Which would be the best approach to still be able to use google's oAuth2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Cross-origin isolation breaking OAuth integration is a known issue (see [the box in this page](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) starting with "Update, April 2021"). Please [apply to the origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) to continue using SharedArrayBuffer without cross-origin isolation.

The team is working to relax the restriction.

Comment: in the future when this restriction is relaxed, would we be able to use SharedArrayBuffer with OAuth popups or just I try to not use popups at all?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to use OAuth popups with SharedArrayBuffer. It's coming closer: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5072630953017344